# How do you remove the gap between inner divs & container div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to figure out why my room and online user divs are not the same width (evenly spaced). 
Also, for some reason there is a gap between each of them and the container div. 
For example, on the left side of the "Rooms" div there is empty white space and then the div container border. I'm trying to make it so that there's no empty white space there. The same thing happens for the "Online Users" div.

I am using Bootstrap 4. When I inspect element the page, that empty gap shows up as div.container.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/adamolof/pen/mdyMQoq).

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/all.min.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Content here -->
      <div class="room"><h4>Rooms</h4></div>
      <div class="chat">
        <div class="chat-box">
          <div class="message"></div>
          <div class="submit">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="online"><h4>Online Users</h4></div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/02926adb38.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.chat {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.room {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.online {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.container .chat .chat-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .chat .message {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.container .chat .submit {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the following classes equal width :

```
.room {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100px;
}

.online {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100px;
}
```

and the outermost `<div>` padding as `0px`

```
<div class="container" style="padding: 0px;">
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.chat {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.room {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100px;
}

.online {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100px;
}

.container .chat .chat-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .chat .message {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.container .chat .submit {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/all.min.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="padding: 0px;">
      <!-- Content here -->
      <div class="room"><h4>Rooms</h4></div>
      <div class="chat">
        <div class="chat-box">
          <div class="message"></div>
          <div class="submit">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="online"><h4>Online Users</h4></div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/02926adb38.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Container` class from bootstrap gives padding. so give padding zero.
I have given `25%` to both `.chat` & `.online` `<div>` and calculated the width of `.chat`. try to implement this and see if this works for you.

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding : 0 !important;
}

.chat {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  width : calc(100% - 50%);
  padding : 0 !important;
}

.room {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width : 25%;
}

.online {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width : 25%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you know how to make Rooms and Online Users the same width? I want the the middle container (chat) to remain the same width.